# PostgreSQL column value depending on previous rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with five columns: `id`, `user_code`, `created_at`, `A`, and `B`, and `start`. `id` is just a key, `user_code` identifies a user associated with that line, `created_at` is a timestamp, `A`, `B`, and `start` can independently take the value 0 or 1.

What I was is to run a query that adds the column `As` and `Bs`, which orders the original table in ascending order according to `created_at` and then the `As` value of a given row equals the number of previous rows with the same `user_code` that had `A = 1` since the last time `start = 1` (and same thing for `Bs` and `B`).

Sample input:

```
 id | user_code | created_at | A | B | start
---------------------------------------------
 00 |     1     |     t0     | 1 | 0 |   1
 01 |     1     |     t1     | 0 | 0 |   1
 02 |     2     |     t1     | 0 | 0 |   1
 03 |     1     |     t2     | 1 | 0 |   0
 04 |     2     |     t2     | 0 | 1 |   0
 05 |     2     |     t3     | 0 | 1 |   0
 06 |     1     |     t4     | 1 | 1 |   0
 07 |     1     |     t5     | 0 | 1 |   1
```

Sample output:

```
 id | user_code | created_at | A | B | start | As | Bs
-------------------------------------------------------
 00 |     1     |     t0     | 1 | 0 |   1   | 01 | 00
 01 |     1     |     t1     | 0 | 0 |   1   | 00 | 00
 02 |     2     |     t1     | 0 | 0 |   1   | 00 | 00
 03 |     1     |     t2     | 1 | 0 |   0   | 01 | 00
 04 |     2     |     t2     | 0 | 1 |   0   | 00 | 01
 05 |     2     |     t3     | 0 | 1 |   0   | 00 | 02
 06 |     1     |     t4     | 1 | 1 |   0   | 02 | 01
 07 |     1     |     t5     | 0 | 1 |   1   | 00 | 01
 08 |     2     |     t6     | 1 | 0 |   1   | 01 | 00
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `COUNT` with `OVER` clause:

```
SELECT "id", "user_code", "created_at", "A", "B",
       COUNT(CASE WHEN "A" <> 0 THEN 1 END) 
          OVER (PARTITION BY "user_code" ORDER BY "id") AS As,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN "B" <> 0 THEN 1 END) 
          OVER (PARTITION BY "user_code" ORDER BY "id") AS Bs
FROM mytable
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/51472/2)

Comment: That's a great solution to the problem I explained! But I forgot to add a detail that was important and that make this solution not quite work :x I edited to add it.